# How do I convert a Makefile to a ROS CmakeList.txt

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, ros

I have simple Makefile to compile my program. The code in makefile is below

```
#
INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/src/linux/include
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall

OBJS = demo.o

all:$(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o demo -lcsmc -pthread

clean:
    rm -f *.o demo
```

I am trying to convert it to a ROS CmakeList.txt, this is how i included my library
`find_library(csmc REQUIRED)`
My executable is called mover
When I run `catkin_make` i get the errors that my functions do not exist

```
mover.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `SmcWSetResolveSpeed'
mover.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `SmcWGetErrorString'
```

How do I solve this problem so that my `catkin_make` runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing `find_library(csmc REQUIRED)` with `target_link_libraries(mover csmc)`

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially asking for a tutorial. There is no good magic makefile -> cmake file program. You'll just have to learn CMake.

https://discourse.cmake.org/t/recommended-cmake-tutorials/2966